# lvalue binding to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue

I am trying to understand how lvalues bind to rvalue references. Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& x) {
    std::cout << x;
}

void g(int&& x) {
    std::cout << x;
}

int main() {
    int x = 4;
    f(x);
    g(x);
    return 0;
}
```

While the call to f() is fine, the call to g() gives a compile-time error. Does this kind of binding work only for templates? Why? Can we somehow do it without templates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `T` is a template argument, `T&&` becomes a *forwarding-reference*. Due to reference collapsing rules, `f(T& &&)` becomes `f(T&)` for lvalues and `f(T &&)` becomes `f(T&&)` for rvalues.

Comment: That makes sense. But suppose I don't need templates, then is there any way to get universal references, say in the example above? I edited the question slightly for this.

Comment: @r.v You can provide a second overload of `g` for lvalues (`void g(int&)`), or you can *move* the lvalues with `std::move`.

Comment: Yes, these are possible solutions but I was hoping we get something in line of a universal reference: given a type T (fixed, not templated), I can match both T& and T&& in one call (no overloads) and then use forwarding, etc. That definitely helps to reduce some redundant code.

Comment: @r.v Sorry, but excluding what I have suggested this is impossible to do without templates. :( Perfect forwarding works great with templates by the way.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I think we have a legitimate use case here though.

Answer (score 1):

**0x499602D2 has already answered your question**; nevertheless, the following changes to your code might give further insights.

I have added a `static_assert` to `f` to check the deduced type:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void f(T&& x) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T&&, int&>::value,"");
    std::cout << x;
}
```

The assert does *not* fail, so the type of `x` in `f` is eventually `int&` (in this particular example).

I have changed how `g` is called in `main`:

```
g(std::move(x));
```

Now the code compiles and the program works as expected and prints `44`.

Hope this helps a bit in understanding rvalue references.

Comment: There's already a template for that: [`std::is_rvalue_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference)