# Perfect-forwaring of the variadic template parameters of a struct

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

In my C++11 code, I have a variadic struct and a function that should use perfect-forwarding for the struct's variadic types such as this:

```
template <typename... T>
struct S
{
    void X(T&&... args)
    {
        Do(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Just assume that `Do` is a free-standing variadic function. Given a type `struct V { int x, y; };` I want to call `S::X` like so:

```
S<V> s;
V v = { 1, 2 };

s.X(V());   // Compiles
s.X(v);     // Does not compile
```

The last line produces the following error in Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 with the November 2013 CTP of the C++ compiler:

```
error C2664: 'void S<V>::X(V &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'V' to 'V &&'
You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

I tried mingw 4.8.1 and got a similar error, so it doesn't seem to be a compiler or C++11-support problem:

```
Source.cpp:51:7: error: cannot bind 'V' lvalue to 'V&&'
  s.X(v);  // error C2664: 'void S<V>::X(V &&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'V' to 'V &&'
   ^
Source.cpp:17:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void S<T>::X(T&& ...) [with T = {V}]'
  void X(T&&... args)
   ^
```

I was surprised to find out that a call to `s.X(v)` wouldn't work, as that is what universal references and perfect-forwarding are all about, right? While trying to figure out what's going on, I first noticed that it does indeed work when X is a free-standing variadic function, and it also works if I change X to be 'doubly variadic', in a sense:

```
template <typename... T>
struct S
{
    template <typename... T2>
    void X(T2&&... args)
    {
        Do(std::forward<T2>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Now, calling both `s.X(v)` and `s.X(V())` work as expected, however, the relationship between the `T` and `T2` variadic template arguments is now unclear. Reading [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126485/lvalue-binding-to-rvalue-reference%20%22this%20stackoverflow%20question), I get the impression that the original version of X is in fact *not* using perfect-forwarding and universal references at all; instead, when `S`'s template arguments are expanded by the compiler, the definition of `S::X` is also expanded, hence the function's prototype is actually `void S::X(V&& v)`, in which case the error message makes perfect sense.

Can anyone confirm this behavior? Is there a way to have a true perfect-forwarding/universal reference function within a variadic struct without repeating the variadic arguments? If my suspicion is indeed correct, is that a defect of the current C++ standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example :

```
template <typename... T>
struct S
{
    void X(T&&... args)
    {
        Do(std::forward<T>(args)...);
    }
};
```

`T` is evaluated to `V` when you declare `S<V> s`, therefore the only prototype of the generated `X` member function is :

```
void X(V&&);
```

---

Whereas in your second example :

```
template <typename... T>
struct S
{
    template <typename... T2>
    void X(T2&&... args)
    {
        Do(std::forward<T2>(args)...);
    }
};
```

`T` is evaluated to `V&` when you call it with `s.X(v)` so the generated prototype of the member function `X` is :

```
void X(V& &&);
```

which becomes (with reference colapsing) :

```
void X(V&);
```

---

To answer your second question, you either need to repeat the variadic template parameters or use function overloading.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct: Universal references (and thus perfect forwarding) only work when the parameter is of type `T&&` *for a **deduced** `T`*. In your original case, the `T` comes from the struct's tempalte parameters, so it's not deduced.

I can't comment on wether it's a defect in the current standard, but consider this: perfect forwarding works by sometimes (in very specific cases) using `U&` instead of `U` for deducing `T` (where `U` is the actual argument type). That's not possible when the template parameter is already "fixed" by being the parameter of the class.